# Application failed to start on updating spring-boot-starter to 2.2.4.RELEASE caused by spring kafka factory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

on using spring kafka 2.4.1.RELEASE with spring-boot-starter 2.2.4.RELEASE following exception is casued

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory]: Factory method 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerProperties

Comment: You have some kind of mismatched jars on the classpath; it looks like you have an older spring-kafka jar, not 2.4.1; edit the question to show your pom.

Comment: Thanks Gary Russel for the reply, Yes the pom was not using the property instead older version was hardcoded.